# Query on Estimated Savings

Tags: lighthouse

We have a question regarding the time saved by rectifying the opportunities presented on Google Lighthouse.

**Question 1:**
We have embedded an example of a Lighthouse scan from our company's website.

These are the opportunities identified:

1. Reduce initial server response time (estimated savings: 1.57s)
2. Enable text compression (estimated savings: 1.02s)
3. Reduce unused CSS (estimated savings: 0.72s)
4. Reduce unused JavaScript (estimated savings: 0.55s)
5. Eliminate render-blocking resources (estimated savings: 0.55s)

[image: Lighthouse Opportunities]

May I understand if assuming all issues addressed by Lighthouse is addressed by our developers, then we should be able to save at least 4 minutes and 41 seconds of performance speed (4m41s is derived by totaling all the estimated savings identified by Lighthouse)?

**Question 2:**
If it is true that I am able to save 4 minutes and 41 seconds of performance speed, which of the 6 metrics do I match this data against?

[image: Lighthouse Metrics]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, summing the time estimates in the Opportunities section gives you 4.41 seconds, not 4 minutes 41 seconds. In addition, these are just time estimates, so the actual savings could vary. These estimates are mostly there to help identify the most important areas that can be focused on, prioritizing engineering efforts.

The metrics shown in the second image are what the score is calculated with, not the opportunities in the first image (though improving those will likely help your score). web.dev (a resource by Google, who makes Lighthouse) has some great resources [explaining what the metrics mean](https://web.dev/user-centric-performance-metrics/) and also [how the score is calculated from those metrics](https://web.dev/performance-scoring/). These metrics taken together can help you see a bigger picture of how your page is performing.